sh: script for adding ip adresses to ipset list from file
I have my home linux server as gateway router, and i would like to block some IP addresses from file, im newbie on bash compl, and my script doesnt work :(
Legend: i have file on my PC what contain blacklisted IP, on router i have iptables rule for block ip addresses from ipset list :
blocked_ip
blocked_ip1
blocked_ip2
blocked_ip3

i write script sh:
#!/bin/bash

scp -P 21 root@192.168.0.10:/blocked-IP/dump.xml /var/scripts/IP
cd /var/scripts/IP

#  Get ip from dump.xml
/usr/bin/python2.7 /var/scripts/IP/parser_ip.py > /var/scripts/IP/ip_addresses.txt

# Sort
/usr/bin/sort -u  /var/scripts/IP/ip_addresses.txt > /var/scripts/IP/sorted_ip.txt

# Split the file with addresses into parts of 900,000 lines
/usr/bin/split -l 900000 -d /var/scripts/sorted_ip.txt /var/scripts/IP/sorted_ip_split

# ipset

#/sbin/ipset -F blocked_ip
n=1;
for file_ip in `find /var/scripts/IP -type f -name "sorted_ip_split*"`
do
cat $file_ip | while read line
do
/sbin/ipset -A "blocked_ip${n}" $line
done
let "n=n+1"
done



#/sbin/ipset save manual_block  > /etc/iptables/manual_block.list
/usr/sbin/service netfilter-persistent save

So i have only one ipset filled.... my cycle doesn't work, why ?

I'm not really clear what the problem is here. While there are some problems with your script (it's generally inadvisable to loop over the output of find like you're doing here), it looks like it will correctly loop over the files in your /var/scripts/IP directory, incrementing n for each file. What exactly happens when you run it?

For what it's worth, I would probably rewrite your script to remove all those intermediate files and instead do something like this:
#!/bin/bash

BATCH_SIZE=1000
OUTPUT_DIR=/var/scripts/IP
EXTRACT_SCRIPT=/var/scripts/IP/parser_ip.py

mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR" && cd "$OUTPUT_DIR" || exit 1
scp -P 21 root@192.168.0.10:/blocked-IP/dump.xml "$OUTPUT_DIR"

/usr/bin/python2.7 "$EXTRACT_SCRIPT" |
  /usr/bin/sort -u |
    cat -n |
    while read -r i addr; do
        if ((--i % BATCH_SIZE == 0)); then
            setcount=$((setcount + 1))
            echo "create example${setcount} hash:ip family inet"
        fi
        echo "add example${setcount:-0} $addr"
    done |
    ipset restore -exist

Here, we simply produce a sorted list of addresses on stdout and then consume that in a while loop that generates output suitable for ipset restore.
The cat -n is there to add line numbers to the input, which saves us from having to calculate that in the shell script.
We increment the ipset name every $BATCH_SIZE addresses. I've set BATCH_SIZE to 1000 in this example, but you can make it as big as you want (within any limits imposed by ipset).

I would also probably rewrite parser_ip.py to (a) not require the now obsolete Python 2.7 and (b) to read from stdin and write to stdout. This would allow us to create a single pipeline, like this:
ssh root@192.168.0.10 cat /blocked-IP/dump.xml |
  /usr/bin/python "$EXTRACT_SCRIPT" |
  /usr/bin/sort -u |
    cat -n |
    while read -r i addr; do
        if ((--i % BATCH_SIZE == 0)); then
            setcount=$((setcount + 1))
            echo "create example${setcount} hash:ip family inet"
        fi
        echo "add example${setcount:-0} $addr"
    done |
    ipset restore -exist


Thanks a lot for rewrite! Its works, but dump have 900.000 IP....... and this create only 152k rows, editing BATCH_SIZE Does not help. i guess need loookup this: if ((--i % BATCH_SIZE == 0));
